# Can you animate over an image using Javascipt?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, canvas

I currently have an image that is a map of Clear Lake. I want to overlay arrows onto the map. I was trying to use the HTML DOM method, but when I run the animation, it creates it above the image on the page. Does anyone have any tips on how to make this work? Do I need to move to the HTML canvas in order for this to work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Interpolation</title>
        <style>
            #container {
                width: 400px;
                height: 400px;
                position: relative;
                background: white;
            }
            #animate {
                width: 50px;
                height: 50px;
                position: absolute;
                background-color: red;
                position: {0,0};
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><button onclick="myMove()">Click Me</button></p> 
        <div id ="container">
            <img id = "myImage" src = "test.img"/>
            <div id ="animate">  
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
            function frame() {
            if (/* test for finished */) {
                clearInterval(id);
            } else {
                /* code to change the element style */ 
            }
            }
            function myMove() {
                var elem = document.getElementById("animate");   
                var pos = 0;
                var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
                function frame() {
                    if (pos == 350) {
                    clearInterval(id);
                    } else {
                    pos++; 
                    elem.style.top = pos + "px"; 
                    elem.style.left = pos + "px"; 
                    }
                }
                }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried to increase the `z-index`  of the container?

Comment: Put the image inside `#container` too, and position `#animation` to `{0, 0}`.

Comment: Relative positioned container (just a div should fine). Then absolute positioned children to "hover" over it. Or use an actual canvas element and draw upon it. Either way should work

Comment: @Teemu Are you saying putting the ```<img id = "myImage" src = "test.img"/>``` in the ```<div id ="container">``` or in the ```<style>```?

Comment: Yes, into `div`. I've updated my previous comment.

Comment: @Teemu I have updated my post using your recommendation, but it does not work.

Comment: @V.Sambor What do you mean by z-index? What should I increase it to?

Comment: @icecub Should i change the position in my animate to hover?

Comment: Umm ... `position` should be `top: 0px; left: 0px;` ... You've also to adjust the coordinates in the script. `event.clientX/Y` are relative to the viewport, not to the clicked element, unless following mouseY was intended, ofcourse.

Comment: @wiebecoding I've answered bellow how to animate over the image, could you please check ?

Comment: @V.Sambor I cant find you question. I copied your code and played around with it and it worked. However, how did you make the rectangle.

Comment: @V.Sambor How would I make it an arrow?

Comment: I don't know if I understood well your entire question, that's why I deleted the answer  :-| After re reading your question it is not clear to me, what is your exact problem.

Comment: @wiebecoding could you make a jsfiddle of your issue? You seem to have removed pieces of code, which makes it harder to replicate the issue, and a runnable example always helps.